# Can't convert Class to Interface with Generics C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

So, this might seem similar to other issues with the same title out there - but I couldn't find a solution to the specific issue i'm having. Please feel free to link a solution if there's one already out there.

**Background:**

I have this method which needs to accept a generic interface as a parameter type (as other objects also need to call this function)

I have simplified the problem to not include the exact details of the problem, as it's confidential. I have replaced it with Animals. **typeOfAnimal** below is a **Fox**, **Cat**, etc...

The `IDefinition<T>` object is an interface encompassing any definition of any Animal to be passed in.

The 'problem' i'm facing isn't exactly a blocking issue, this works, but it's using a standard I wouldn't be all too comfortable using..

It involves creating an instance of `DefinitionOfFox`, using this as an instance of the class to call a method on the class, and then passing this instance into that method as a param because it's needed further in that method. As expected, this works fine (passing in `DefinitionOfFox` as a type `IDefinition<T>`), but I want to refactor it so I'm not passing in the `DefinitionOfFox` object to the `DefinitionOfFox` class... and instead the `DefinitionOfFox` class creates the instance itself.

**CURRENT STATE**

```
public class Fox : Animal {
   public void Init()
        {
            DefinitionOfFox definition = new DefinitionOfFox();
            definition.Method1<Fox>(this, definition);
        }
}
```

```
public class DefinitionOfFox : IDefinition<Fox>
    {
        public void Method1<T>(T typeOfAnimal, IDefinition<T> definition)
        {
            OtherService otherService = new OtherService();
            otherService.Method2<T>(typeOfAnimal, definition);
        }
    }
```

All works fine in the current state, but it doesn't sit right with me passing the class instance in as a param to it's own class.

**IDEAL STATE**

```
public void Init()
        {
            DefinitionOfFox definition = new DefinitionOfFox();
            definition.Method1<Fox>(this);
        }
```

```
public class DefinitionOfFox : IDefinition<Fox>
    {
        public void Method1<T>(T typeOfAnimal)
        {
            DefinitionOfFox definition = new DefinitionOfFox();
            OtherService otherService = new OtherService();
            otherService.Method2<T>(typeOfAnimal, definition);
        }

    }
```

`OtherService` class and `Method2`
**NB** This method must be called from the DefinitionOfFox class, not from the Fox class.

```
public  class OtherService
    {
        public void Method2<T>(T typeOfFox, IDefinition<T> definition)
        {

        }
    }
```

I get a compiler error for `definition` when trying to pass this into the `OtherService.Method2()` method.  It complains that it can't convert `DefinitionOFox` to `IDefinition<T>`.

How come this works in the current state, but not in the Ideal state? And is there a way I can have my Ideal state? It is the same object that is getting passed into the method, it's just created at a different time.

[image] error says
**Argument 2: Cannot convert from ....DefinitionOfFox to .... IDefinition**

If this doesn't make sense, I can elaborate - no problem. Just let me know

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you please add a full [mre]?

Comment: `OtherService.Method2(typeOfAnimal, definition);` why can't that be `OtherService.Method2(typeOfAnimal, this);` ?

Comment: @Fildor I think this happens due to generics.

Comment: can you show the definition of method `OtherService.Method2` ?

Comment: Signature of `OtherService.Method2` would be great.

Comment: @GuruStron How? If OP can pass a newly created `DefinitionOfFox`, he can surely pass `this` which is of the exact same (not generic) type?

Comment: @Fildor OP can't, cause it is not working now (with `new DefinitionOfFox()` or `this`).

Comment: @GuruStron Haha, right. Missed that part.

Comment: Without further info, it's hard to tell anything, but do you mean something in this direction: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rs1BLt ?

Comment: ^^ After edit: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kyvmtj

Comment: Why do you want `Method1` to be generic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `Method1` just should not be generic or have non-generic overload:

```cs
public class DefinitionOfFox : IDefinition<Fox> 
{
  public void Method1(Fox typeOfAnimal)
  {
     DefinitionOfFox definition = new DefinitionOfFox();
     OtherService.Method2(typeOfAnimal, definition); // or OtherService.Method2(typeOfAnimal, this); based on goals
  }
}
```

> How come this works in the current state, but not in the Ideal state

Because in the ideal state the generic parameter `T` is closed with `Fox` so it "matches" for `T` and `IDefinition<T>`, for the "ideal" state imagine if your code was compiling then what should happen in the case of `Method1<Rabbit>(...)` invocation is `DefinitionOfFox` suitable for `IDefinition<Rabbit>` parameter?

If you still want your method to be generic and you want to create a new instance of `IDefinition<T>` inside then you will need to generic parameters with corresponding constraints:

```cs
public class DefinitionOfFox : IDefinition<Fox>
{
    public void Method1<T, TDefinition>(T typeOfAnimal) where TDefinition : IDefinition<T>, new()
    {
        IDefinition<T> definition = new TDefinition();
        OtherService otherService = new OtherService();
        otherService.Method2<T>(typeOfAnimal, definition);
    }
}
```